# How can I get a call to aUIView.presentScene(aSKScene, transition: aSKTransition) to act in unison with aUIView.addSubview(aUITextField!)?

Tags: ios, swift, callback

**How can I get a call to aUIView.presentScene(aSKScene, transition: aSKTransition) to act in unison with aUIView.addSubview.**

***Without*** the transition, there is **zero** problem .. ***with*** the `SKTransition` the `UITextField` **happens 1st** and then the `SKTransition` – not in unision.

Like, the `UITextField` is planted in the `view` of the `ViewController` and sits around waiting for the `SKTransition` to catch up

**Code**

```
func showScene(theSceneName: String) {

    if let ourScene = SKScene(fileNamed: theSceneName) {
                                    
        addTextFieldToVC(toSceneName: theSceneName)
        // NB: theSceneName is passed by Reference so we can
        //     return here before we call presentScene(...)
        addGamePiecesToScene(toScene: theSceneName)

        if let theView = self.view as! SKView? {
            theView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            theView.showsFPS = true
            theView.showsNodeCount = true
                
            // Finally, present the scene
            let theTransition = SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 2.0)
            theView.presentScene(ourScene, transition: theTransition)
        }
            
    }   // if let ourScene
        
}   // showScene


func addTextFieldToVC(toSceneName: String) {

    if (toSceneName == "GameScene") {
        if let theView = self.view as! SKView? {
            aUITextField = UITextField(frame:CGRectMake(x: aXValue, y: aYValue))
            theView.addSubview(aUITextField!)
        }
    }

}


func addGamePiecesToScene(toScene: SKScene) {

    myRoom = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: roomImg))
    myRoom!.zPosition = roomZposition
    // etc with .size, .position
    toScene.addChild(myRoom!)

}
```

As the above shows, I add the UITextField 1st and add the SKSpriteNode images 2nd.

Yet they are **not in sync** with the SKTransition. They appear in sync just **without** the SKTransition.

FWIW, I have tried this sequence within `showScene`, but no changes:

```
theView.presentScene(theSceneName, transition: theTransition)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    addTextFieldToVC(toSceneName: theSceneName)
}
```

I have also started to experiment with Completion Handlers:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        
    super.viewDidLoad()
                
    setupScene()
        
    // Completion Handler for showScene()
    showModifiedScene {
                 
        if thisSceneName == "GameScene" {  // a global var
            addTextFieldToVC(toSceneName: thisSceneName!)
        }
            
    }
     
}   // viewDidLoad


// modified for callback option??
func showScene(theSceneName: String) {

    if let ourScene = SKScene(fileNamed: theSceneName) {
                                    
        addGamePiecesToScene(toScene: ourScene)

        showModifiedScene()
            
    }   // if let ourScene
        
}   // showScene


func showModifiedScene(completionBlock: () -> Void) {

    if thisSceneName == "GameScene" {  // a global var
        if let ourScene = SKScene(fileNamed: thisSceneName!) {
            if let theView = self.view as! SKView? {
                theView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                theView.showsFPS = true
                theView.showsNodeCount = true
                    
                let theTransition = SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 2.0)
                theView.presentScene(ourScene, transition: theTransition)
            }
        }

        completionBlock()
    }
                
}   // showModifiedScene
```

Again, ***without*** the transition, there is **zero** problem .. ***with*** the `SKTransition` the `UITextField` **happens 1st** and then the `SKTransition` – not in unision.

I am **still** chugging with this .. but I figure it’s time to call for a few reinforcements!  I'll still work away while I am waiting for the calvary.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the text view, then wrapping the call to `presentScene()` in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async()`.

That way the text field will be added to your view before you begin presenting that view.

Comment: I wish I could knight you a "hero" .. but not this time .. maybe later. With or without the `DispatchQueue`, the `UITextField` object appeared first, remained stationary and waited until `presentScene` did its thing. I believe the central problem is that the `UITextField` belongs to the `ViewController` and the various `SKScenes` belong to the `View`? – How I wish I could 'fake out' the `UITextField` and force it to become an image, like a SKSpriteNode.

Comment: What is the effect you are after?

Comment: When the `SKTransition` happens, I want both the added `UITextField` (added with `addSubView` for the `ViewController`) and the `CGScenes` (added via `addChild`) to take part in `SKTransition` together, not separately. I could 1st call`presentScene` then wrap `DispatchQueue` around `addUTextField` with a `duration` - but its effectiveness is dependent on CPU speed.  I need to understand Callbacks. But I really think I’ll only be happy with adding all the `CGScenes` and the `UITextField` at once for the `SKTransition`. **Not** having the `UITextField` waiting for the `SKTransition`

Comment: Haven't figured out all the specifics **yet** - but the answer is to use `SKLabelNode`, not `UITextField` so I can use `.addChild` on all the contents.